# Second Monitor on 14.04 with Intel Graphics

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors

I am on a DELL laptop with Intel 3rd Graphic controller and I am try to connect a second monitor but everytime i am on displays menu no extra monitor is being detected.
I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and if everyone needs more information I am more than happy to give them of course.
Hope you don't judge me I am kind of newbie in Ubuntu.